# scatter plot for 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'

Tags: matplotlib

I have this matrix from TfidfVectorizer, so is it possible to plot a graph out of it?

(0, 6164) 0.019338613120625153
  (0, 8791) 0.030431754891299245
  (0, 13418)    0.019338613120625153
  (0, 12251)    0.040303890966260525
  (0, 2896) 0.017899943021264794
  (0, 2172) 0.12091167289878157
  (0, 3413) 0.040303890966260525
  (0, 6571) 0.014970123315314715
  (0, 13039)    0.015495789594635422
  (0, 11488)    0.03593540116095009
  (0, 12423)    0.030431754891299245
  (0, 11803)    0.017899943021264794
  (0, 14555)    0.017899943021264794

Answer (score 1):

`plt.scatter` can be employed as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

# create a 15000x15000 sparse matrix with some toy data
N = 15000
npnts = 1000
# mtrx = csr_matrix(([y for (x1,x2),y in data], ([x1 for (x1,x2),y in data], [x2 for (x1,x2),y in data])), shape=(N, N))
mtrx = csr_matrix((np.random.uniform(0, 0.2, npnts),
                   (np.random.randint(0, N, npnts), np.random.randint(0, N, npnts))),
                  shape=(N, N))

# convert the dense matrix to dictionary format, get an array of xy-coordinates and an array of values
mtrx_dict = mtrx.todok()
xy = np.array(list(mtrx_dict.keys()))
vals = np.array(list(mtrx_dict.values()))

# create a scatter plot
plt.scatter(xy[:,0], xy[:,1], s=5, c=vals, cmap='inferno')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Depending on the meaning of the data and what you want to show, you can experiment with coloring, alpha, sizes etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or is there something I misunderstood?